# Could not load type 'Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule' from assembly 'Castle.Windsor'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, windows-7, c#-4.0, castle-windsor, iis-7.5

I'm getting this error intermittently during debugging an MVC3 application. Intermittently being that if I modify the code within the app, rebuild and test, the error appears. If I make a change the web.config (e.g. add a space), the error goes away and everything works as expected. Thoughts?

Web.config

```
<system.web>
...
<httpModules>
  ...
  <add name="PerRequestLifestyle" type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.Windsor" />
</httpModules>
</system.web>
  <system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="PerRequestLifestyle" type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.Windsor" />      
....
</modules>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you edit the web.config it will force the application to be destroyed and re-started, this may not be happening when you edit and re-build the code.

What kind of change are you making when the error is thrown?

Comment: Keith, Thanks for the reply. I found that I had 2 modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests within the web.config. Removing the duplidate resolved the issue.

Comment: Same thing worked for me. We had a separate <location> element defined for our Elmah configuration. It has a <modules> sub element with the attribute `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests`. This was in addition to the main <modules> element. Removing the attribute from the Elmah specific config seems to have resolved the issue.